# What can Neovim/Vim's :terminal do that tmux can't?

Tags: tmux, terminal-buffer

I've been using tmux for a while, and recently tried `:term` in Neovim for a few days.

Aside from some small trivial differences, it seems mostly the same to me? What is the advantage of using `:term`? What can I do with it that I can't do with tmux.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously an opiniated question. Here's my opinion.

Advantages of neovim (or Vim) terminal:

- Normal mode gives the power of Vim inside a terminal window
- Can use vimscript to customize mappings and commands

Advantages of tmux:

- Allows persistent sessions

  - IMHO this is the most important aspect of tmux, because:
  - It allows to detach a session, then leave the computer, log on from a different computer and continue the session from where we left it
  - It also helps when working through bad network connections, since one may always reconnect to the tmux session if the network connection is lost
- Fits better into a workflow where Vim is only one of many useful tools. I often use tmux even if I don't work with text editing at all.

Comment: I agree with you but, about the normal mode in vim terminal, it's not as useful as a normal buffer because you can't edit text and you're not able to move the cursor. All mappings are not available in terminal, like autocompletion or `<C-o>`. Anyway, I know there is no absolute answer. Thanks for your opinion.